# In Graphite, how to cap data to a constant when data is above that constant?

Tags: constants, graphite

I thought that my request would be pretty common but I haven't been able to find a solution for it.

The subject/summary says it all, but to give more color, I have a metric that is typically between 0 and 100 but in some weird cases it shoots up to a few 1000s which dwarfs the rest of the 0-100 data.

My goal is that when the data is beyond 100 set it as say 110 so that I know it's a value is beyond 100.

The only thing I could find is removeAboveValue() but when used it looks as if the data is missing.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use [`transformNulls`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.transformNull) so query would look like:

```
transformNull(removeAboveValue(some.metric.avg, 100), 110)
```

Note that above will also set 110 to the real gaps. Of course you could use again `transformNull` in the origin metric to mark gaps as ... -1 (or whatever)

```
transformNull(removeAboveValue(transformNull(some.metric.avg, -1), 100), 110)
```

But this introduces magic `null has value`, besides it's bad (misleading) it's not always possible (if metric can have negative values, zero or whatever).

Next solution is:

1. Prepare line with only exceeding datapoints and set theirs value to `110`. It may be done in many ways. Let's take some simple approach:

   - get only point above 100

     ```
     removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100)
     ```
   - reduce its value to 1 using division by the same metric:

     ```
     divideSeries(removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100), removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100))
     ```
   - set value to 110 - multiple by 110:

     ```
     scale(divideSeries(removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100), removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100)),110)
     ```
2. Merge the prepared metric with the one with values below threshold (using `removeAboveValue`). As merge function, in this case, use [`minSeries`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.minSeries):

   ```
    minSeries(
      removeAboveValue(some.metric.avg, 100), 
      scale(
        divideSeries(
          removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100), 
          removeBelowValue(some.metric.avg, 100)
        ), 
        110
      )
    )
   ```

Comment: Thanks Kwarunek! I was really hoping for a simpler solution. For now, I'll stick with the removeAboveValue() function and inform the user of the chart/metric that "missing" data points are likely due to the scenario I presented above.